# URL rewriting affects the GET values

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I've rewritten this URL :

```
http://localhost/mysite/admin/edit-post.php?edit-post=post1
```

To this URL :

```
http://localhost/mysite/admin/edit-post/post1
```

Using this Rewrite Condition :

```html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^admin/edit-post/(.+)/?$ admin/edit-post.php?edit-post=$1 [L]
```

And my PHP Code is :

```html
<a href="edit-post/<?php echo $post_detail['slug'] ?>" >Edit</a>
```

URL rewrittened and everything is alright and now the problem start.

I'm trying to fetch post details and displaying it on my Edit page, When i click edit i'm getting the value of clicked post through get method, So here is the code that i'm using.

```html
if (isset($_GET['edit-post'])) {
    $post = $_GET['edit-post'];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE slug = '$post' ";  
  [My fetch code].... 
}
```

Now what I'm getting from this get value is : **post1.php/post1**

But what I need is : **post1**

```html
Getting Wrong
$query = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE slug = 'post1.php/post1' ";

Expected
$query = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE slug = 'post1' ";
```

I hope i explained my issue well. Please help, how can i solve this issue.

Comment: Anyone help pls, I've stucked with this issue for more than an hour.

Comment: Your rule looks like it should work but it might be that your other rules are conflicting with this one. Please post your full htaccess file in the question.

Comment: @ChrisHaas That's a different question.

Comment: Try disabling `MultiViews`, it is most often the culprit when you have such a partial overlap between the fake path, and physically existing files.